# strtok() (C) unexpected result

Tags: c, file, strtok

i open a text file like this:

```
    <2504><titlos><desc><paragwgos>
```

and i want to save its content into these variables:

```
int num; //2504
char t[100], d[100], p[100];//titlos , desc , paragwgos
```

so i write this part of code:

```
void readB(char *buffer, char *title, char *description, char *producer)
{
    char s[2]="><", *token;
    token = strtok(buffer, s);
    strcpy(title, token);
    token = strtok(NULL, s);
    strcpy(description, token);
    token = strtok(NULL, s);
    strcpy(producer, token);
}


int main()
{
    int num;
    char t[100], d[100], p[100], buffer[408];
    FILE *f;
    if ( (f = fopen("inp.txt", "r"))==NULL )
    {
        printf("Error opening requested file!");
        exit(1);
    }
    fscanf(f, "%*c%d", &num);
    fgets(buffer, 408, f);
    readB(buffer, t, d, p);
    printf("%d %s %s %s\n", num, t, d, p);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

but instead of "2504 titlos desc paragwgos"
it shows: "2504 titlos desc pa"
Anybody sees what's wrong with the code?

Comment: Not related to the question, but don't use `read` as function name.

Comment: Agree with @EugeneSh. And `char s[2]="><"` should be `char s[3]="><"` or `char s[]="><"` or `const char *s = "><"`.  The string is actually 3 bytes long  when you count the nul terminator `'\0'`.

Comment: @ECEntuaGREECE please don't edit the question on-the-fly in response to comments. It messes with the flow of the dialog.

Comment: @ECEntuaGREECE it's considered good practice to check the return value from `strtok()`. You'll get **robust** code that way, but code that will *fall in the wind* when done your way.

Comment: @WeatherVane i'm not sure i get what you mean(mybad english i guess), but if you mean what i think, i just use it this way because this is code for a project at school where you read from a text file which you know that is formatted like this

Comment: It's when you think you "know" that you are most likely to set yourself up for a nasty surprise.